# How would I convert this 4x4 transiton matrix to a 2x2 transition matrix while maintaing that all rows sum to 1

Tags: probability, matrices, dynamical-systems, markov-chains

Say I have a transition matrix with 4 states labeled 1 to 4 as follows:

```
matrix = [[.25,.25,.5,0],
          [ 0,.25,.5,.25],
          [.25,.25,.25,.25],
          [.25,.25,0, .5 ]]
```

Say I want to convert this transition matrix to one with only 2 states, good and bad, where states 1 and 2 from the original matrix are part of the "good" state and states 3 and 4 are part of the "bad" state.

How would I convert the original transition matrix to a 2x2 matrix, while keeping the properties that the rows sum to 1 (transition matrix property).

Adding all the transitions doesn't work. For example the ways of going from "good" to "good" would be summing up going from state 1 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 1, and 2 to 2 but that's .75 and if you do the same calculate for "good" to "bad" the row ends up summing to 2 instead of 1.

Thank you.

Comment: you need the stationary probabilities to do this right. Then, after you have that vector, you can do good conditional probabilities, ie given state 1 or 2 now, what is the probability that you'll be in 1 or 2 after transition.

Comment: Remark that, in general, this coarsening destroys the Markov property. The probability that it transitions to the state "bad" given that it is at the state "good" is not well defined: it depends on the microscopics, i.e., on the particular state within "good".

Answer (score 2):

lets call your matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$, and assume $Av = v = [v_i]$ for some nonnegative definite $v$ whose entries sum to $1$ ie its the stationary probabilities for the states.

The best way to come at your problem is to use $v$ to work out what the transitions are from a 'good' state ie state 1 or 2. So, given that you're in 1 or 2, you have a probability of $v_1/(v_1 + v_2)$ of being in state 1, and you can work out the probability of being in state 2. The row that you might write down for transitions from 'good' would be $$ \frac{v_1}{v_1 + v_2}[a_{1i}] + \frac{v_2}{v_1 + v_2}[a_{2i}] $$ and then, by summing the first pair of entries, and the last pair, you have a row of the matrix for transitions between good and bad states.

Hope that's relatively clear.